# How to construct a byte in hex format with out of sequence nibbles in C++

Tags: c++

I have a sequence of numbers as follows from the following string:

```
std::string mcc_mnc = "514328";
```

The string is made up from MCC (Mobile Country Code), MNC (Mobile Network Code). The string would always be 6 chars long, when the MNC is less than 100, it is prepended with 0.

I need to construct 3 hex bytes as follows:

```
|  <---     8 bits       -->    |
| 4 bits        | 4 bits        |
| ------------- |:-------------:|
| 1             | 5             |
| 8             | 4             |
| 2             | 3             |
```

Each line should be a hex number, using C++ std libraries (pre C++ 11):

```
 00010101 (15)
 10000100 (84)
 00100011 (23)
```

This is encoded according to the ECGI field of the User-Location-Info 3GPP standard. See screen shot for format.

[image]

Comment: Are these two numbers decimal? And do you need to encode them using BCD?

Comment: As you only care for single digits from the string, you can access the digits using std::string::operator[], and do something like `byte0 = (mcc_mnc[1]-'0') << 4 | ( mcc_mnc[0]-'0')` and similar for the other bytes. Or use `atoi` on substrings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you maybe want something along these lines:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;

std::string mcc_mnc = "514328";

byte ecgi[3];

ecgi[0] = byte(mcc_mnc[0] - '0');
ecgi[0] = ecgi[0] | byte((mcc_mnc[1] - '0') << 4);

ecgi[1] = byte(mcc_mnc[2] - '0');
ecgi[1] = ecgi[1] | byte((mcc_mnc[5] - '0') << 4);

ecgi[2] = byte(mcc_mnc[3] - '0');
ecgi[2] = ecgi[2] | byte((mcc_mnc[4] - '0') << 4);

std::cout << std::hex << int(ecgi[0]) << '\n';
std::cout << std::hex << int(ecgi[1]) << '\n';
std::cout << std::hex << int(ecgi[2]) << '\n';
```

Subtracting the `ASCII` digit value (in the string) from `'0'` gives its numeric value to be stored in the given nibble.

**Output:**

```
15
84
23
```

Comment: That looks close but I can't use C++ 17 (supports byte), i am limited to pre C++ 11.

Comment: @eeijlar I created my own type alias called `byte` using `typedef` that will be fine with `c++03`.